# Select all records within the last month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server T-SQL syntax how can you find all records within the last/max transaction month for a specific customer?

Given the following records:

```
CUSTOMER_ID | TRANSACTION_DATE
------------------------------
00001       | 04/21/2013
00001       | 05/01/2013
00001       | 05/14/2013
00002       | 06/08/2013
00002       | 07/01/2013
00002       | 07/28/2013
```

The output of the query should look like:

```
CUSTOMER_ID | TRANSACTION_DATE
------------------------------
00001       | 05/01/2013
00001       | 05/14/2013
00002       | 07/01/2013
00002       | 07/28/2013
```

The best I've come up with is this query (not tested), which looks horribly inefficient.

```
select customer_id, transaction_date
from customer_table outer
where concat(month(transaction_date), year(transaction_date)) = (
    select concat(month(max(transaction_date)), year(max(transaction_date))) 
    from customer_table inner 
    where outer.customer_id = inner.customer_id
)
```

Comment: `WHERE [TRANSACTION_DATE] >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0) AND [TRANSACTION_DATE] < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())+1,0)`

Comment: @Tim please no shorthand - just spell it out as `MONTH`. To understand why, check out what `y` and `w` do. :-)

Comment: @Aaron I said it was inefficient! I'm still new to TSQL, so give me some slack.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, actually I kind a like mm shorthand, it makes my code shorter, but still readable :)

Comment: @Roman the point is about being explicit, which makes it much more readable to others. If you get in the habit of using `m` and `mm`, eventually you will use `y` or `w` and that will bite you because it's not obvious that they don't mean what most people think they mean. Do you really think an abbreviation really makes that code *more* readable to people?

Comment: well, I always use two letter shorthand, no problem with `y` and `m`. And of course I don't think that abbreviation makes my code more readable, for me it's about the same as `month` but it's shorter.

Comment: @Roman do what you want in your own code and follow all of the bad practices you want. I'm just giving you some advice about what you should do when providing answers here ***for other people*** who don't necessarily know all of the things that you do and will think that this is a good practice.

Comment: AaronBertrand as you see - I've tried to follow your advice on this page for a change :) . Looks like @TimSchmelter also using shorthand with no problem.

Comment: @Roman and that's why I left my comment in the first place. *shrug*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM  Table1 T1
      JOIN
      (
        SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,
               MAX(TRANSACTION_DATE) AS TRANSACTION_DATE
        FROM   Table1
        GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
      ) T2
      ON T1.CUSTOMER_ID = T2.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE MONTH(T1.TRANSACTION_DATE) = MONTH(T2.TRANSACTION_DATE)
      AND YEAR(T1.TRANSACTION_DATE) = YEAR(T2.TRANSACTION_DATE)
```

I am leaving the above for reference.

I have come to the following:

```
WITH MyCTE AS
(
  SELECT  [CUSTOMER_ID],
          MAX(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [TRANSACTION_DATE]), 0)) AS StartOfMonth
  FROM    Table1
  GROUP BY [CUSTOMER_ID]
)

SELECT T2.* 
FROM MyCTE M
Join Table1 T2
ON DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [TRANSACTION_DATE]), 0) = StartOfMonth
```

Which is very similar to the Roman's. The difference is that i have an equality rather than greater than. The execution plan seems better, and that is why i post it.

I have [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f016/33) the fiddle of all, but still Roman's first seems to be the best.

Comment: This type of self-join is problematic in terms of reads. It will also include rows from other years that happen to be in the same month.

Comment: I guess it all depends on how much data there is

Comment: Sure, but why use a method that is guaranteed to have high reads ever? Just because the data might be small, now, for this OP, that won't be the case for everyone.

Comment: +1  But also try all conditions in the join (no where) with year before month.

Comment: take a look at my second approach - it will utilize the index on transaction_date (if there's one)

Comment: @Blam the order shouldn't matter - do you have any examples where changing the order of filters affects the optimizer? It's not guaranteed to process the filters in the order they're written. Also they're going to prevent an index seek of any kind anyway because the `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` expressions are not sargeable.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes in big queries and using hints I have successfully used the order to effect the query plan.   Even on a simple query moving from the where to the on has changed the query plan.

Comment: @Blam I wasn't talking about moving `WHERE` to `ON` (which can also change semantics), I was talking about changing `ON condition1 AND condition2` to `ON condition2 AND condition`. Do you have any REAL EXAMPLES where that has made any difference in the plan or execution time? If not, then my point remains - order shouldn't matter.

Comment: actually I think that performance of that one could be terrible, - no usage of the index

Comment: @Shaun, if you're going to use this solution, please change the non-sargeable `MONTH()/YEAR()` stuff to `T1.TRANSACTION_DATE >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, T2.TRANSACTION_DATE),0)`. Currently - even without an index on the datetime column - this has the worst plan of all the solutions (that work) on this page.

Comment: I know, but i cannot figure anything that wouldn't resemble Roman's answer and i hate repeating other people's work.

Comment: And just out of curiosity, should i ever change this answer, even if i did find any shiny elegant way to do it? It is accepted, so if in the future someone sees this he will get a wrong impretion of what was accepted as an answer and why we have so many posts underneath it (after all it will be a shiny elegant solution that people are arguing about)...

Comment: I would say - go ahead and change it. If somebody wants to see history of edits - he could do it. But people will get correct and shiny answer

Comment: Yep, go ahead and change it, because what should show as the accepted answer should be the best answer when possible (even if that was informed by others). Just be sure to include relevant comments in the revisions.

Comment: @AaronBertrand As stated, yes in big queries and using hints I have successfully used the order to effect the query plan.  You can believe me or not.

Comment: @Blam well, I saw Elvis today. Believe me or not.

Comment: @Aaron I swapped the where clause for the `T1.TRANSACTION_DATE >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, T2.TRANSACTION_DATE),0)` you suggested and it works too.

Comment: @jyparask I agree that if you have a better answer go ahead and post it. This query works well enough for me, but I would use a better query if you post it.

Answer (score 2):

```
;with CTE as (
    select
        customer_id, transaction_date,
        rank() over(
                   partition by customer_id
                   order by year(transaction_date) desc, month(transaction_date) desc
        ) as row_num
    from customer_table
)
select *
from CTE
where row_num = 1
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17977)

another way to do it:

```
;with CTE as (
    select
        customer_id, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, max(transaction_date)), 0) as date
    from @customer_table
    group by customer_id
)
select ct.*
from CTE as c
    inner join @customer_table as ct on
        ct.transaction_date >= c.date and ct.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17984)

Comment: I don't think this provides the requested results. It gets the last entry of each month, but it is requested to get all the entries of the last month.

Comment: damn missed that, wait a sec

Comment: In the second version, you don't need the additional AND < clause because you already know there can't be data later than the month c.date falls in. However you *do* need an additional join clause to match customer_id (and I can't explain why the fiddle works without it).

Comment: @AaronBertrand yeah, you right and SQL fiddle works because there are different months for different customers! thank you, I'll change the query